# Magento Layout - Include block only if admin setting is true

Tags: magento

Using magento layout files - is it possible to include a block, only if an admin setting is true.

Exactly like you can do using the ifconfig property when using action method="setTemplate".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly.  The `ifconfig` mechanism is the only conditional like structure in the Layout Update XML system that ships with Magento.

If you're comfortable creating modules and custom blocks class though, you can achieve the results you want pretty easily.

1. Create a custom Block class that extends whatever block you're interested in conditionally adding.
2. Create a new `_toHtml` method in your class with the conditional logic you want.  If the tests pass have your method `return parent::_toHtml`, otherwise have it return an empty string.

Comment: Just out of interest Alan - if i use this method then I would have to conditionally set a template from within the blocks toHtml method.  Would you recommend using the blocks in this way when developing modules to be used by different people.

Comment: It's all a mater of what you want to support.

Comment: I suppose - although it feels like using the blocks to programatically create and manage templates etc make a custom module feel more closed for extension and customization.  But yeah - at the end of the day its all a matter of choice I suppose.